# Sharepoint Online O365 prevent document from being downloaded

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want my users to be able to view/read a document but I don't want to give them the permissions to download, edit, print the document.

I set their permissions to: read.

When I see the document in my library the option download/edit isn't there. Awesome!

But when I open the pdf file I got redirected to safari. There I got the option to email the file. Which is basically the same as downloading.

That's why I tried to post a word doc because microsoft should be able to manage their own app right? In Word Online I don't find the option download, nor the ability to email the file. The only problem is that I can't get rid of the Printing button. When I press this button my .docx file will be converted to a pdf file. This gives my users again the freedom to email/download the file.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try below :-

Create a security group that has the **View Only permission**

Create and configure a document library

Test with another user that the download is not possible

Let me know if any concerns.

Comment: Hi Yash, that's exactly what I tried, and unfortunately that does not work. Is IRM really the only solution? View only helps me to get rid of the download and edit permissions but leave the printing option untouched.

Comment: Yes I guess IRM is the only approach in that case.  There is a link which describes this below .  https://www.cloudfronts.com/restrict-download-and-print-option-for-sharepoint-online-document-library/